# Why the size of my Person is 10 bytes, and not 16 ?

Tags: c++, class, visual-studio-2015, size

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

class Person {
    char name[10];
    int age;
};

int main(void) {
    const size_t size = sizeof(Person);
    cout << size << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Output is:
`16` and that's ok, because 10 bytes (char[10]) is rounded to 16 by Visual Studio 2015 compiler. If I comment out the `int age;` line, then the output is `10`(is it 2+8 from rounding values?) Why not still 16 if compiler rounds values to `2`,`4`,`8` and `16` ?

Why compiler is not consistent and doesn't print `14` for both `char name[10];` and `int age;`. And `10` for only `char name[10];` (when I comment out `age`)

Comment: *"Why not still 16 if compiler rounds values to 2,4,8 and 16 ?"* Because it doesn't do that. It just aligns members. Read about padding.

Comment: Thanks, I've just read about this and checked out the duplicate. Resolve my doubts :)